Setting up lndk and need lnd to use http/2
Does anyone know how to get an lnd node to use http/2? I didn't see any parameters to use in the lnd conf file.
Basically lndk is returning this for me.
2024-09-11T20:52:09.129688888-04:00 WARN hyper::client::client - Connection is HTTP/1, but request requires HTTP/2

I figured it out. I'm not sure why but i had to add rpclisten=localhost:10009
I didnt have it defined cause i thought that was the default value.
